# How to insert a javascript variable inside an <a href> html tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to insert a javascript variable inside an html link such that each time the value of the variable is changed, it changes immediately in the html link.

I have tried already many possiblities but unsuccesfull.My code is as follows:

```
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>

CATEGORIE NAME: <input id="first_name">
DEVICE NAME: <input id="last_name">
<button id="say">Send!</button>

<hr>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function say_hi() {
    var fname = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
    var lname = document.getElementById('last_name').value;

    var html = 'CODE: <b>' + fname  + lname;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
}

document.getElementById('say').addEventListener('click', say_hi);


</script>
    <a href="http://barcodes4.me/barcode/c39/ +$html.png">Click this link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Please what should i so so that the link takes directly each time the value of the variable "html" and adds in as part of the link

Comment: I don't understand the question. `anchorElement.href = url; anchorElement.click()` in your `click` Event?

Answer (score 1):

The DOM API is fairly simple. It follows almost exactly the same convention as the HTML. For example, the `href` attribute of the `a` tag is the `href` property of the `a` object.

What you need to do is make your `a` tag easier to find:

```
<a id="this_link" href="">Click this link</a>
```

Now in your script you can simply do:

```
var link = document.getElementById('this_link');
link.href = "http://barcodes4.me/barcode/c39/" + html + ".png"
```

Comment: ok thanks ! but should i add something inside the href=" "?? here <a id="this_link" href="">Click this link</a>

Comment: because when i click now it goes to no other page

Comment: From my understanding, there is no reasonable value you can put in there because the url path requires a value from a variable. You can either hide the link until it gets a value (`link.style.display = 'none'` or `'inline'`) or execute the function at once when the page loads